# Using jQuery-barcode.js with ColdFusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to use `jQuery-barcode.js` to output a barcode to my **ColdFusion** page when the page loads.

**The script is as so:**

```
<cfquery datasource=somedsn name="qGetUserInfo">
query here
</cfquery>
```

**Then the `script`:**

```
<script>
##(document.ready(function() {
    '$("##bcTarget").barcode("#qGetUserEmail.BarCode#", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30, output:bmp}));'
});
</script>
```

**Then the `div`:**

```
<div id="bcTarget">

</div>
```

What I understand is that the barcode should print within the `div`, but it does not.

When I view the source, the script is getting the barcode from the query.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help woudl be appreciated.

**Update:**

Here is the source output:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="../js/jquery-barcode.js"></script> 
<script> 
#(document.ready(function() { $("#bcTarget").barcode("1036744588", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30, output:bmp})); }); 
</script> 
<div id="bcTarget"> 
</div>
```

Comment: I would show the source output rather than the CF part of this. Chances are this is going to be largely a jquery question. I don't see any cfouptput above but  I assume you are getting actual values from #qgetuseremail.barcode#.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to include the cfoutput. The script is in a cfoutput. When I view the source I see the actual barocde from the query

Comment: Here is the source output:<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../js/jquery-barcode.js"></script>


<script>
#(document.ready(function() {
 $("#bcTarget").barcode("1036744588", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30, output:bmp}));
});
</script>
<div id="bcTarget">

</div>

Comment: FYI: To add additional code, just [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18518393/edit) (so it is easier to read than in comments).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I just setup your code and found the issue.  First, you have an extra closing parenthesis ")" at the end of your code:  output:bmp}));

Also, the output value is a string so it needs to be in single quotes.

So in that one line of code, remove the single quotes that encase the line, remove the extra closing parenthesis, and put the format in single quotes to treat it as a string:

```
$("#bcTarget").barcode("1234567", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30, output:'png'});
```

That should work.

Comment: No, it did not. I'll keep plugging away.

Comment: Really? I get the following barcode :http://cl.ly/image/0c3c3F0X1s2e  Not pretty but it works.  Here's my test code:

<head>
<title>Barcode</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.barcode.0.3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:600px;" id="bcTarget"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
   $("#bcTarget").barcode("192837465748392", "code39",{barWidth:2, barHeight:30, output:'bmp'});
});
</script>
</body>

Comment: Note, I did have to set the height on my div to see it full size.  When I set my div height to 500px, I get a code more like this: http://cl.ly/image/311y343W0E1Z

Comment: Great, glad to hear it works now.  Would you mind marking this as the correct answer please? Thx